# if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a homomorphism and $p$ is an integer-coefficient polynomial, then: $f(p(r))=p(f(r)) \ \forall_{r \in \mathbb{R}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-homomorphism

Why is that true that if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a ring homomorphism and $p$ is an integer-coefficient polynomial, then: $$f(p(r))=p(f(r)) \ \forall_{r \in \mathbb{R}}$$

I know that if $f$ is a ring homomorphism then:

- $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$
- $f(ab) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$
- $f(1) = 1$

And that polynomials generate a ring.

But how is that useful?

Comment: Verify that $p$ is the identity on the integers, and then write out exactly what $p(f(r))$ and $f(p(r))$ are.

Comment: Hint : first, prove by induction that forall $r\in \mathbb R$, $f(r^n) = (f(r))^n$ and that for any $n\in\mathbb Z$, $f(z) = z$. Then, use the fact that a general integer coefficient polynomial can be written $p(r) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k r^k$ for some integers $a_k$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What do you mean by: "p is the identity on the integers"?

Comment: @SolubleFish You mean: $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, right?

Comment: "$p$ is the identity on the integers" means $p(n)=n$ for every integer $n$.

Comment: just a correction, it should be "$f$ is the identity on the integers"

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense, but why would that be the case? I thought f(n) = n only if n is the unit of multiplication.

Comment: A ring homomorphism sends 1 to 1

Comment: And only 1 to 1, so why would it be the identity on ALL the integers? I don't get it.

Comment: every positive integer is a sum of 1's, then use the property of being a homomorphism

Comment: Ohh, I think I understand it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $f(1)=f(1+0)=f(1)+f(0)$ so $f(0)=0.$

By induction on $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $f(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(r_i)$ and $f(\prod_{i=1}^n s_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n f(s_i).$

In particular when $r_i=1$ for each $i$ then $f(n)=f(\sum_{i=0}^n 1)= f(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i)=$ $=\sum_{i=1}^n f(r_i)=$ $\sum_{i=1}^n f(1)=$ $\sum_{i=1}^n 1=n.$

And so  if $n\in \Bbb N$ then $0=f(0)=f(n+(-n))=f(n)+f(-n)=n+f(-n),$ so $f(-n)=-n.$

So $f(v)=v$ for every integer $v.$

And if $s_i=x$ for each $i$ then $f(x^n)=f(\prod_{i=1}^nx)=f(\prod_{i=1}^ns_i)=$ $=\prod_{i=1}^nf(s_i)=\prod_{i=1}^nf(x)=f(x)^n.$

Let $p(x)=v_0+\sum_{i=1}^nv_ix^i$ where  each  $v_i\in\Bbb Z$. For $i>0$ let each $v_ix^i=r_i$ and we have $$f(p(x))=f(v_0)+f(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i)=f(v_0)+\sum_{i=1}^n f(r_i)=$$  $$=f(v_0)+\sum_{i=1}^nf(v_ix^i)=$$ $$=f(v_0)+\sum_{i=1}^nf(v_i)f(x^i)=$$ $$=v_0+\sum_{i=1}^nv_if(x)^i=p(f(x)).$$

Comment: We also have $f(q)=q$ for every $q\in\Bbb Q$. Because if $v\in\Bbb Z $ and $n\in\Bbb N$ then $f(v/n)=(1/n)nf(v/n)=$ $(1/n)f(n)f(v/n)=$ $(1/n)f(n\cdot v/n)=$ $=(1/n)f(v)=(1/n)v=v/n.$